# How to count swaps in bubble sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to write a program to count only how many swaps and calculates the check-sum of the sorted array. However, I am not sure why the counter is not getting the correct swaps! I have traced it many times, this should be working perfectly fine. What am I missing?

The program works buy putting only a positive numbers as an input for the array, to  terminate the program and display the swaps you should enter "-1"

a simple example of an input of:

> 1 4 3 2 6 5 -1

the output should be

> 3

but the output is not correct at all.

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubble_sort(unsigned long long int arr[], int n)
{
    int swaps=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Swaps: " << swaps << endl;
}

int main() {
    int count=0;
    unsigned long long int  input_ar[1000];
    cout << "Enter the numbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cin >> input_ar[i];
        if (input_ar[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    bubble_sort(input_ar, count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the output should be 3? Your algorithm works by performing the following swaps (there are values, not indices): Swapping 4 3
Swapping 4 2
Swapping 6 5
Swapping 3 2
Swaps: 4

Comment: @Paul92 Perhaps OP is swapping Tootsie Rolls?

Comment: The program is working correctly, except that temp should be unsigned long long int, not just int.  4 swaps: 1 (4 3) 2 6 5,  1 3 (4 2) 6 5, 1 3 2 4 (6 5), 1 (3 2) 4 5 6.

Comment: The OP's problem stems from believing that `1 3 2 4 5 6` is fully ordered. However 2 is typically considered to be a smaller number than 3, necessitating a second pass and a fourth swap to get `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Answer (score 2):

For the series `1 4 3 2 6 5`, you first swap `4` and `3` (one swap), then `4` and `2` (two swaps), then `6` and `5` (three swaps). That leaves you with the array like `1 3 2 4 5 6`, so it's till not sorted completely, you will have another swap to get the `2` in its correct place, leading to four swaps (if the code works as it should).

Comment: That makes sense. then how to fix this to be like. (1  4) 3  2  6  5  - pass
1 (4  3) 2  6  5  - swap
1  3 (4  2) 6  5  - swap
1  3  2 (4  6) 5  - pass
1  3  2  4 (6  5) - swap
1  3  2  4  5  6  - end
This should be 3 swaps performed not 4

Comment: @haithamhany You can't because you would no longer have implemented bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

Removed previous answer.

You program does work correct; it should be 4. For this to work, I took of the unsigned long long and simply made it to int. Add the following code right after the swap variable becomes incremented and you will see exactly each swap occur.

```
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Swap count: " << swaps << endl;
            cout << arr[j] << " is swapped with " << arr[j + 1] << endl;
            for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
                cout << arr[a] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
```

Results:

Old array: 1 4 3 2 6 5

Swap count 1: 
3 is swapped with 4; 
1 3 4 2 6 5

Swap count 2: 
2 is swapped with 4; 
1 3 2 4 6 5

Swap count 3: 
5 is swapped with 6; 
1 3 2 4 5 6

Swap count 4: 
2 is swapped with 3; 
1 2 3 4 5 6

Swaps: 4

New array: 1 2 3 4 5 6

I suggest next time you have a problem with something not working out right, you need to use cout statements in specific parts to make sure what the program is doing is being done right.

Comment: The input parameter to bubble_sort() is count, not 1000.

Comment: The main issue that the Swaps should be 3 Swaps not 4 as follows: (1  4) 3  2  6  5  - pass
1 (4  3) 2  6  5  - swap
1  3 (4  2) 6  5  - swap
1  3  2 (4  6) 5  - pass
1  3  2  4 (6  5) - swap
1  3  2  4  5  6  - end.  but it displays 4 swaps instead of 3

Comment: Yes you're right about the count. I didn't see that. Let me see if I can fix the issue much simpler.